# Best practice to store and show special characters in MySQL like double quotes across a web application

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this PHP function which gets some JSON data as an input and stores it in a datatable.

One of the values is a **Note** value, which obviously can be anything, the user enters.

In order to store this, I came up with a prepared statement that looks something like this:

```
function InsertIntoTable($user, $note) {
    $con = new mysqli(...);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO datatable (UserID, Notes) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $note); //i also tried "mysqli_real_escape_string" on the $note variable but it didn't work: added more backslashes

    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return "OK";
    }
    else {
        return "Error";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}
```

After an insert I usually go into MySQL workbench to check the value and I can see that a row looks like this:

```
USERID       |  NOTES 
someuserid   | \"double quote\"
```

The insert was successfull, but then, in my javascript based mobile app for example, where I read into the same data table and get the values, I will get the escape slashes at the beginning of the special characters.

If I manually go into MySQL Workbench or phpmyadmin, and insert a row myself, with some note that contains double quotes, then it turns out just fine, the escape characters are no longer there (not even in the database)

So I would like to know, what is the best way to store user notes in the database, where the content can be basically anything, and what's the best way to query them, to get them back in their EXACT form (like how the user inserted it)

LE: Ok, I just tried a trick: in the function I write the following line:

```
$note = 'this is a "double quote"';
```

If I run this, it inserts it perfectly, and I can read it perfectly from the mobile app or the web app.
What I get from this, is that the $note value might not arrive correctly to the function (it might already have the escape characters...)

Full PHP code snippet:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  foreach($data as $item) {
     $userid= $item["User"];
     $note = $item["Note"];
     InsertIntoTable($userid, $note);
  }

  ...
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you `echo $user.'<br>'.$note;` right before `$stmt->execute()` and see if the string is exactly what you expect it to be?

Comment: Hmm. This is how it looks when I echo it \"double quotes\". 
I am getting this value from a textbox and sending it from a C# application via json like this: string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData);
When I watch the json object in C#, it doesn't have any backslashes or anything.

Comment: It sounds like you have a completely unrelated problem compared to the code you've posted. BTW, nice job on the prepared statements; it does my heart good to see prepared statements :-) Can you show the PHP code which actually receives the data? Basically, show the piece of code which actually calls the `InsertIntoTable()` function.

Comment: I think it will also help if you post the C# code which builds the URL which calls your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! The C# app was sending the wrong data to it, it just showed it in the watch as plain text, but it did send it with escaped quotes, so the source of the problem was at the root of it.